# Array list intValue()

Tags: java, object, arraylist, int

Hey i have an array list of numbers and when i try to convert into `int` i get `The method intValue() is undefined for the type Object` error. This is the code snippet.

```
while (1>0) {
        a = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
        if(a == -999)
            break;
        else {
            list.add(a);
            i++;
        }
    }
    int j;
    int[] array = new int[list.size()];
    for(j=0;j<list.size();j++) {
        array[j] = list.get(j).intValue();
    }
```

Comment: Your `List` hasn't been declared with an `Integer` generic type argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have created a list of objects and not Integers. Hence when you call `intValue` then it says that there is no such method for type Object. I would recommend that you define your list as list of Integers using generics. Here is the sample:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

If you don't do so then you  list created will hold the items of class `Object`. And then you need to cast the object fetched from the list everytime to `Integer`.